# Android Loopers:Unable to get messages from UIThread to worker thread

Tags: android

```
private Handler workerHandler; // instance variable of UIThread
```

In onCreate() method

```
WorkerThread wt = new WorkerThread();
workerHandler = wt.getHandler();
wt.start();
```

Using this below SeekBar listener method to send messages to WorkerThread's Queue

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        workerHandler.sendMessage(workerHandler.obtainMessage(99,String.valueOf(progress)));
    }
```

WORKER THREAD:

```
private Handler handler;

//getHandler() method 

public void run() {
        super.run();  
        Looper.prepare();

        handler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);  
                if (msg.what == 99)
                    Log.d("RTR","Message from Main Thread:"+(String)msg.obj);
            }
        };

        Looper.loop();
```

But when I change the `SeekBar` there is 'program unfortunately stopped' message. What might be the reason?

UPDATE: The problem is with Handler of the Worker thread `workerHandler`.It is still `null`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
WorkerThread wt = new WorkerThread();
workerHandler = wt.getHandler();
wt.start();
```

line 1 instantiates a new `WorkerThread` object and calls its constructor. **Note: This doesn't actually create a running thread, nor does it call the `run()` method**

Line 2 calls `getHandler()` on the `WorkerThread` object and returns the member variable `workerHandler` which has never been set to anything, so it is `null`

Line 3 starts the thread.

The problem is that the `run()` method in the thread isn't called until **after** line 3 has been executed.

Please have a look at the `HandlerThread` provided by Android. It pretty much does the same thing as this. Search for tutorials or examples to see how to use it. For example: http://stephendnicholas.com/archives/42

Comment: So I guess line 2 should be wt.start() and everything would be fine.Will try this.Thankyou

Comment: Well, no. That isn't enough. Because you can't be sure when the thread will actually be started. Calling `start()` just tells the VM that you want it to start the thread. The VM will get around to doing this whenever it wants to and you have no control over that timing. Because of this you need to make sure that your `getHandler()` method actually blocks until the thread starts running and the run()` method has been called to ensure that the member variable `handler` has been initialized. This is what Android's `HandlerThread` already makes available and that's why I suggested you use it.

Comment: Yeah,already been using HandlerThread coz of this problem.Just curious to know what's the problem here.Thanks David